# Can't find matching function static inline objective -c c++

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode

I have a problem with compiling my objective-c/c++ project. I get an error  no matching function to call to. I used the same code in another project in objective-c without problems in an out off the box SingleView Application and without configuring my build settings. So maybe somebody can help me to tell me what i missed. Thanx

```
// recursive search function - looks for a match for a given combination of vertex and  texture coordinates. If not found, returns UINT_MAX

static inline GLuint VertexTextureIndexMatch(VertexTextureIndex *node, GLuint matchVertex, GLuint matchTextureCoords)
{
if (node->originalVertex == matchVertex && node->textureCoords == matchTextureCoords)
    return node->actualVertex;

if (node->greater != NULL) 
{
    // error no matching for call function VertexTextureIndexMatch
    GLuint greaterIndex = VertexTextureIndexMatch(node->greater, matchVertex, matchTextureCoords);
    if (greaterIndex != UINT_MAX)
        return greaterIndex;
}

if (node->lesser != NULL)
{
    GLuint lesserIndex = VertexTextureIndexMatch(node->lesser, matchVertex, matchTextureCoords);
    return lesserIndex;
}
return UINT_MAX;
}
```

Comment: Recursive function cannot be inline.

Comment: Ok but why its working in my other project, the difference between them  is one objective c and the other is an objective c / c++ project.  I don't grasp that

Comment: Different compiler ignores `inline` keyword.

Comment: Ok Thank you ,last question what is best approach to avoid this problem.
Do i have to rewrite the code to example c++ code? or something else?

Comment: Find a solution, took some time,,, the function above and some more functions not displayed were in a separate .h . I cut them out of it and paste them directly on the page with the function calls.. Very simple thus if you know. :)  it took me some hours.  So it means that static inline recursion function are working in my compiler.
I think that the inline extension is  not working on a separate file in my project. Why, maybe somebody tell me about that. Anyway my code works :-)